# how do we clear the cache using supercacher in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

> I used supercacher to clear the cache it only clears the cache in back
>   end. but the changes are not reflected in front end.
>
> How do we clear the cache in front end for a wordpress site.

please suggest some ideas for that
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super cacher will clear the cache  perflectly. I have cleared the cache through cpanel.